# How can I Identify in stored procedure if a certain column is being updated?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need to do a check to see which stored procedures have table updates in them that don't update certain columns. I found the code of the stored procedure in the sys.sql_modules, but I don't know how could I make this check. The stored procedures may contain more UPDATEs and INSERTs. I am using Microsoft SQL.

Comment: What's wrong with using `not like '%column%'` ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are curious to find stored procedures that update TblA and do not update ColA, you could do something like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM sys.sql_modules 
WHERE definition LIKE 'UPDATE TblA' AND 
definition NOT LIKE 'SET ColA';
```

This can get ugly if people do not format their source well, but you can adapt this technique to handle that if you need to.